# Socket.io: Overwritten generateId() gets executed, but the returned id seems to be ignored

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am trying to overwrite generateId. I used for that the example from the [docs](https://socket.io/docs/v3/server-api/). But the behaviour is strange. `generateId` gets executed, but `socket.id` is like a regular id, instead of the desired result `"custom:id:" + 1`.

## Code

```js
const express = require('express');
const socketIO = require('socket.io');
const http = require('http');

const app = express();
app.set('port', 5000);
const server = http.Server(app);
const io = socketIO(server);


io.engine.generateId = (req) => {
    console.log('This here gets printed')
    return "custom:id:" + 1;
}

io.on('connection', socket => {
    console.log(socket.id);
})


server.listen(5000, async () => {
    console.log('Starting server on port 5000');
});
```

Expected Output: `custom:id:1`

Actual Output: `MNWAC86CdPXB7thTAAAA`

## package.json Dependencies

```json
  "dependencies": {
    "base64id": "^2.0.0",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "cookie": "^0.4.1",
    "css-loader": "^5.0.1",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^4.5.0",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "ngrok": "^3.4.0",
    "sass": "^1.29.0",
    "sass-loader": "^10.1.0",
    "socket-io": "^1.0.0",
    "socket.io": "^3.0.3",
    "socket.io-client": "^3.0.3",
    "style-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "webpack": "^5.7.0",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^4.0.2"
  }
```

Comment: For starters, `return "custom:id:" + 1;` is not unique.  It generates the same value every time.  Try at least making a unique value using a counter like the example in the doc shows.

Comment: @jigirend00 I already tried that out and it makes no difference, if you do that or not. Actually I had the bug in another project, where I tried out the solution from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18294620/reuse-socket-id-on-reconnect-socket-io-node-js). I only created this file to "isolate" the error and make it more clear.

Comment: @Atr0x can you show the code used with unique ids as jfriend00 suggested? I also think the issue could be around uniqueness of the returned id

Comment: I'm struggling with the same issue!

Answer (score 3):

I was having this problem also. Apparently it is due to a change in socket.io version 4. The code below is from node_modules/socket.io/dist/socket.js. It appears the change is for security reasons.

```
if (client.conn.protocol === 3) {
    // @ts-ignore
    this.id = nsp.name !== "/" ? nsp.name + "#" + client.id : client.id;
}
else {
    this.id = base64id_1.default.generateId(); // don't reuse the Engine.IO id because it's sensitive information
}
```

client.id will have the value you return in your generateId but it won't be used as we expected.

After looking through the source and debugging, it looks like the socket id can be set in an io.use (example below.)

```
var idIndex = 0
io.use((socket, next) => {
    socket.id = `ID_${idIndex++}`;
    next();
});
```